# Exchange Web Services identifying spoofing

Tags: security, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Let's assume that i use a telnet session and send an email with address alice@domain.com to bob@domain.com but in fact i am charly@domain.com...

On alice@domain.com i have a WCF web service running that's monitoring that specific mailbox using Exchange Web Services...

How can i tell that the message from bob@domain.com actually came from charly@domain.com?

I am using Visual Studio 2010, with .NET 4.0 and EWS managed API 1.1
The server is configured to use SSL and i have Exchange Server 2007 SP1.

i tried the two properties "Sender" and "From" but they are identical and both point to bob...
nothing in the message header actually points to charly... everything points to bob... any ideas? things that i might have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that identity spoofing is not possible using an email service, you can use cryptographic signatures. [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) / [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) and [S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) are common technologies in use to implement this.

This requires every mail sent from alice@domain.com to be signed by her with a secret. The key or certificate she uses to do this must be trusted by your webservice. Your webservice can verify that a mail has really been sent by Alice by checking the validity of the signature. Only someone who possesses the secret of Alice can create such a valid signature. If the signature is wrong or missing, your webservice can trigger an alert.

Should the real Alice forget to sign an email, your service will trigger as well, because it cannot tell if it really was Alice who sent that mail. You also need to make sure that the secret in use can only be accessed by Alice. If you need further informations, you should read up on [public key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

Comment: PGP and S/MIME are not quite applicable in my context, and i'm sorry i did not give full details about this. The idea is that a user can only send emails from intranet, but also can send emails from his/hers mobile phone... Outlook can sign those mails if it's running on the computer but from a mobile phone it isn't actually possible. Some restrictions could be added but using PGP is not an option. I need something that's built in EWS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can detect such practices with EWS Managed API at least I don't see anything that could be helpful in this situation. Unless valid sender is recognized with use of some cryptographic signatures or you can somehow mark messages from valid senders with your own extended property that only you (your software) create and uses you have to believe that mail was sent by whoever is showing up in Sender or From property